# Is the product of two categories with cofibrations still a category with cofibrations?

Tags: ct.category-theory, exact-categories, cofibrations

Given two $k$-linear categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ which are "categories with cofibrations" (in the Waldhausen sense),
is the product category $\mathcal C\times \mathcal D$ still a category with cofibrations?

Further, what about the Waldhausen $S$-construction? In this case, do we have 
$$S_n(\mathcal C\times \mathcal D)=S_n(\mathcal C)\times S_n(\mathcal D)$$
for every $n$?

Comment: Being a Waldhausen category is a structure, not a property. Do you mean to ask whether $C \times D$ can naturally be equipped with the structure of a Waldhausen category?